# Trilogy of books with both a sci-fi and a fantasy world and quantum magic?

Tags: story-identification, quantum-physics

I read at least the first book in what I believe to be a trilogy in the 2000's. The book/s may have had Quantum in the title/s.

What I recall is that there are two storylines in the book.  One is set in a future Earth/solar system, there was definitely some space travel. The other story line has a more fantasy like setting with magic, and at least at the end of the first book portal travel to other dimensions. The two storylines converge at the end of book when the protagonists from the fantasy setting travel to the sci-fi setting, and find themselves on a space station and meet with the protagonists from this setting.

The magic used by the fantasy people is actually discovered to be some sort of quantum manipulation of physical space, possibly sufficiently advanced tech, and is referred to as quantum magic by at least some people at some point in the story.

I can't remember reading the other books in the trilogy. I think the first book had the space station on the cover.

Comment: I think this may be it.

Comment: @user14111 I may have read more than one, but The Spell of Rosette definitely sparks some memories. However, my memories of this book/series are very sparse, the cover may be one of the things I misremembered. Post as an answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps something in [Kim Falconer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Falconer)'s [*Quantum Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?31576) series, which is divided into the [*Quantum Enchantment*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?31695) subseries with two books. [*The Spell of Rosette*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1709272) (2009) and [*Arrows of Time*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1444481) (2009), and the [*Quantum Encryption*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?31377) subseries with three books, [*Path of the Stray*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1415771) (2010), [*Road to the Soul*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1709322) (2011), and [*Journey by Night*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1808733) (2011). I haven't read any of them, and have only found out a little about them online.

*The Spell of Rosette*, ISFDB synopsis:

> *WorldCat:* Rosette is a child of two worlds: Gaela, steeped in magic, and an Earth choked with failing technology. The key to their survival is literally in her blood - a spell passed down through her family line to preserve the one they are sworn to protect. Unaware of her lineage, Rosette runs scared when her family is murdered.

*The Spell of Rosette*, [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6249203) blurb:

> Rosette is a child of two worlds: Gaela, steeped in magic, and an Earth choked with failing technology. the key to their survival is literally in her blood, a spell passed down through her family line to preserve the one they're sworn to protect. Unaware of her lineage, Rosette runs scared when her family is murdered. She takes refuge with Nell, a shape-shifting high priestess of the ancient blood, who teaches her the arts of witchcraft, stars and sword. Shadowed by the fabled Kreshkali, queen of the underworld and mistress of the wolf-like Lupins, Rosette and the temple cat, Drayco, find themselves little more than a step ahead of those who will do anything to control the portal that links the many-worlds. 'At last - a writer who is right up my alley. this debut novel from Kim Falconer is a magnum opus of originality and insight into Earth's technological future and occult past. this intricate and intriguing tale perfectly blends the physical, quantum, cyber and spiritual realms into one of the best fantasy books I've read in ages!' traci Harding, author of the Ancient Future

*Arrows of Time*, [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6661918-arrows-of-time) blurb:

> When a portal spins Rosette and Jarrod off in different directions, Rosette is caught in a loop of repeating events. A strange bard helps her find a way back home, but things have changed -- Jarrod is missing, her mentor is a child and women are forbidden to carry swords.
>
> While Kreshkali leads the survivors on Earth, Rosette and her Temple Cat turn to the future for help -- but which future?
>
> Time is their only hope, and it′s playing tricks ...

*Path of the Stray*, [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/8739989) blurb:

> The magical lands of Gaela are on the brink of war when Tryn Bistoria fi nds herself trapped in the taboo caves above Corsanon. As she and her familiar escape, a terrible power is unleashed from another time. On a distant Earth, Janis the 'techno-witch' must hide Jarrod from those who want to destroy him. But in the crossover to Gaela with the shape-shifting Lupins, Jarrod and a stray pup disappear. In a desperate search, Janis' daughter Ruby learns what must be done if everyone is to survive.

*Road to the Soul*, ISFDB synopsis:

> *WorldCat:* A mysterious artifact leads Jarrod to Gaela's lost southern continent where he discovers a sentient being like himself. Ruthless and extremely dangerous, this other version has captured Janis Richter. Luka Paree and Janis' daughter, Ruby, are playing a dangerous game with Earth's dictatorship. If ASSIST discovers the portal to Gaela, all is lost.

*Road to the Soul*, [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13062500-road-to-the-soul) blurb:

> With the second book in her latest trilogy, bestselling author Kim Falconer delivers another searing and imaginative journey of intimacy and adventure, magic and technology. Road to the Soul returns to the hidden world of Gaela, an agrarian based magical world where all things — animal, tree, stone, river and storm — are considered equal.
>
> Sequestered on Gaela, Jarrod bides his time, staying hidden until a girl named Bree finds an artefact that shouldn’t exist. The mystery leads Jarrod back to the land of the lost southern continent where he discovers a sentient being like himself, only this version is programmed for survival at any cost.
>
> Janis Richter is at the mercy of Jarrod's ruthless counterpart and Jarrod may be unable to save her. Luka Paree and Janis' daughter, Ruby, are playing a dangerous game with the controlling faction on Earth, ASSIST, and prepare to flee through the portal to Gaela. But they may be leaving it too late ... trackers hunting resistance members are closing in on them.

*Journey by Night*, [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12307328) blurb:

> When Parallel Worlds Collide . . .
>
> Desperation leads Nellion Paree to the forbidden
> spell … but she accidentally awakens a power that
> could destroy the many-worlds forever.
> Rosette and her familiar Drayco return to
> Corsanon to face an invasion. They soon join the
> temple cats and shape-shifting wolves to make a
> fi nal stand against their enemies.
> On a future Earth, Kreshkali uncovers a portal
> built by the allied states. Now the survival of both
> worlds is in her hands … but the only way out is
> straight through the armies of ASSIST.